# Bootstrap file not found when using built-in vendors with jekyll-assets

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I have a jekyll site and am trying to use jekyll-assets built-in support for bootstrap.

Here's what I've done so far:

Updated my `Gemfile` to include:

```
gem "jekyll-assets"
```

Updated my `_plugins/ext.rb` file with the following:

```
require "jekyll-assets"
require "jekyll-assets/bootstrap"
require "jekyll-assets/font-awesome"
```

Updated my `styles.scss` file with the following:

```
@import "font-awesome";
@import "bootstrap";
```

When I run `jekyll build`, I get the following errors:

```
Liquid Exception: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap. Load path...
jekyll 2.1.0 | Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
```

If I remove `@import "bootstrap";`, the font-awesome code is correctly added to my `styles.css` file, so I think I have everything else set up properly.  It's just that I'm doing something wrong that prevents bootstrap from working properly.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this issue was caused by a change in the asset paths for the bootstrap-sass gem used by jekyll-assets.

This issue is now fixed in jekyll-assets >= 0.8.1